# Javascript Array and assign them to variable, but first value as undefined. why?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

When making an unordered list from JS by using Array, first value is undefined.

```
var list; //box for accumulating list tags
var arr = ['menu1', 'menu2', 'menu3', 'menu4'];

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    list += '<li>' + arr[i] + '</li>';
}

document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML = list;
```

result:

```
<ul id="menu">
undefined
<li>menu1</li>
<li>menu2</li>
<li>menu3</li>
<li>menu4</li>
</ul>
```

But assign null value at first, it will be fine.

```
var list = "";
```

So I want to know what the difference is.

If this question is redundant, I'll delete it soon.

Thank you for stopping by.

Comment: Because initial value of variable (unless specified otherwise) is a special value `undefined`. When converted to String, it's `'undefined'`.

Comment: `list='<li>'+arr.join('</li><li>')+'</li>'`

Comment: thanx raina! That says it all. I'll be cautious when making variable from next time.

Comment: The important thing to note here is that the `+` operator coerces everything to strings if its arguments are incompatible, and `undefined` is stringified to `"undefined"` rather than `""`

Comment: Another thing I did not know that change of data type happens as well.I'll be aware of that too. @Pumbaa, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem Part

That is because when you define a variable & don't initialize, it will be undefined.

```
var list; //list is undefined here
```

So when you are first time saying

```
list += arr[i]
```

So it is basically

```
list = undefined + arr[0];
```

So last output will be

```
'undefined<li>...'
```

## Working Part

You are saying

```
var list = '';
```

So first time it will be

```
list = '' + arr[0];
```

So last output will be

```
'<li>...'
```

Answer (score 1):

No its not, the error lies here

```
list +=
```

That assumes list had some value before and it doesn't have it on the first run and is undefined, that's why the first line is undefined. You should add a check there to assign rather than to concatenate on the first iteration.

Instead of initializing the list with an empty string as being suggested elsewhere (there's no point in concatenating something with an empty string), you should really be doing

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(i==0)
       list = '<li>' + arr[i] + '</li>';
    else
      list += '<li>' + arr[i] + '</li>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript values are undefined until they are initialized.

Let's break down the cases by example to help make this clear.

## Referencing an *Undeclared* Variable

In JavaScript you must declare a variable before you may reference it. For instance,

```
var x;
console.log(x);
```

If you were to just type the following a reference error would occur.

```
console.log(x);
```

## Referencing an *Uninitialized* Variable

Once you declare a variable, using the `var` keyword, it can be used in any expression, but has an initial value of `undefined`. For instance

```
var x;
x === undefined; // true
```

## Give a Variable Type, by Giving it a Value

Once you give a variable a value, or give it any *new* value, you essentially let the interpreter know both the value and the *type* of the variable.

For instance,

```
var x;
typeof x; // undefined
x = 1;
typeof x; // number
x = 'a';
typeof x // string
```

## Mixed Type Expressions

In JavaScript, if an expression is of *mixed type* the the interpreter will coerce one of the values to be the type of the other.

For instance,

```
var x = 1;
var y = 'a';
z = x + y; // '1a'
typeof z // string
```

The type coercion is performed on all expressions, not just `+`, and is not always straight forward. For instance,

```
[] == false // true
```

Answer (score 0):

assign empty string when you declare  `list` variable

when you use `list+=`  means you have already value in list variable but you have not

```
var list=""; //box for accumulating list tags
var arr = ['menu1', 'menu2', 'menu3', 'menu4'];

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  // here is `list` is undefined when loop execute first time 
    list += '<li>' + arr[i] + '</li>';
}

document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML = list;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you define a variable like so:

```
var list;
```

It's `undefined`. To fix this simply make it an empty string, as you have said.

```
var list = "";
```

As a few answers have already mentioned. When you concatenate a `undefined` variable with a string, `undefined` turns into the string `'undefined' + ...`.

Answer (score 0):

JS is a dynamic language so if you just define a var there is no way to know which type is will be. It is another case if you use `var list = "";` You explicitly tell that the type will be string and the concatenation will run in the desired way!